# How to get support of thymeleaf for Intellij Idea 13

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am searching support of thymeleaf for Intellij Idea 13. what is the elegant procedure to add support in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get autocomplete support for thymeleaf in Idea by using settings > file types, remove *.html from the HTML files section and add *.html to XHTML files section.